# Joda DateTime doesn't set date correctly via milliseconds

Tags: java, android, jodatime, android-jodatime

I am providing a millisecond data `1473080981L` which should date to: `September 5, 2016 9:50 PM`. I am doing unit testing and this was my first time to play around with **JUnit**. What I noticed so far is that every time I call:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime.withMillis(1473080981L)
```

It still returns the correct date but currently, at the time of this writing, it is now 10:00 PM in the evening, this method call produces `September 5, 2016 10:00 PM`. **DateTime** did not respect the time I set it to.

Is this the correct behavior? Is there a way I could instantiate a DateTime by setting my own predefined selected date time?

Here is my unit test (please bear with it being pointless, I am learning Unit testing):

```
String testDate = "September 5, 2016 9:50 PM"; // MMMM dd, yyyy K:mm a
String testDateResult1 = DateTimeFormatter.format(dateTime, DateTimeFormatter.FORMAT_DEFAULT_DATE_TIME_12);
String testDateResult2 = DateTimeFormatter.format(thisDay   , DateTimeFormatter.FORMAT_DEFAULT_DATE_TIME_12);

assertTrue(testDate.compareTo(testDateResult1) == 0);
assertTrue(testDate.compareTo(testDateResult2) == 0);
```

My **DateTimeFormatter** looks like this:

```
public static String format(@NonNull DateTime dateTime, String validFormat) {
  org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(validFormat);
  return dateTimeFormat.print(dateTime);
}

public static String format(long dateToMillis, String validFormat) {
  org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(validFormat);

  DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
  dateTime.withMillis(dateToMillis);

  return dateTimeFormat.print(dateTime);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that `1473080981L` is `Sun Jan 18 1970 01:11:20` in UTC Time. You can check it at https://currentmillis.com/

The `withMillis` method may return a new instance. Change:

```
dateTime.withMillis(dateToMillis);
```

to:

```
dateTime = dateTime.withMillis(dateToMillis);
```

or simply do:

```
dateTime = new DateTime(dateToMillis);
```

> [public DateTime withMillis(long newMillis)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withMillis(long))
>   Returns a **copy** of this
>   datetime with different millis. The returned object will be either be
>   a new instance or this. Only the millis will change, the chronology
>   and time zone are kept.
>
> Parameters: newMillis - the new millis, from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
>   Returns: a copy of this datetime with different millis

Demo:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class JodaTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
    dateTime = dateTime.withMillis(1473069000000L);

    System.out.println(dateTime);
    System.out.println(new DateTime(1473069000000L));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2016-09-05T11:50:00.000+02:00
2016-09-05T11:50:00.000+02:00
```